# What are the names and scope of the components shown in these images?

Tags: technology, battletech

I have noticed that on multiple images or miniatures, some tubes appear on the sides of a vehicle. I do not know the names or the scope of these items, but they appear on the vehicles.

- Is it an exhaust pipe? I doubt it, as they use fusion engines.
- An AMS? I also doubt it.
- A grenade launcher? No clue.

Some images with the tubes encircled, for more clarity on the question:

[image: Behemoth 2]

[image: Di Schmitt]

[image: Demon Medium Tank]

Comment: It reminds me of some antitank protection in real life: https://youtu.be/YpmcmKwWzYo?t=48

Comment: Active Protection Armour?

Comment: I don't understand Russian, but from what I got out of the video, it detects when a rocket is approaching the tank at high velocity, and fires out an explosive that detonates the rocket before it hits, so yeah. The angle at which the thing is fired is what reminded of that video when I saw these pictures. Still, there's no proof that's what's depicted.

Comment: Some of them are (only) deployed close to the rear part of the vehicle, where probably you are not expecting an attack from the enemy in a battle. Also the game probably is older that the idea from the video. But your idea sounds good in any case.

Comment: https://www.sarna.net/wiki/Behemoth_II_Heavy_Tank

Comment: @Valorum It looks like it should be an answer

Comment: Seeing as they have no gameplay effect, which I would expect for a weapon or an active defense, I would have to call them "greebles."  The other one: [DI Schmitt](https://www.sarna.net/wiki/DI_Schmitt).

Comment: @Clockwork - I couldn't see anything in the thing that directly answered the question. They must do *something*

Comment: Are smoke generators a thing in Battletech?

Comment: @Shawn Not that I'm aware of. But my knowledge is limited to the game BATTLETECH (2018)

Comment: "A head-mounted **Shield-3 anti-missile system** defended against missiles, while an **anti-personnel pod** in each leg discouraged unarmored infantry." https://www.sarna.net/wiki/Stone_Rhino_(Behemoth) - I came across that looking up [LAMS](https://wiki.mechlivinglegends.net/index.php?title=LAMS) (Laser Anti-Missile System) for Mechwarrior, which has a link to Battletech.

Comment: @Clockwork I found reference to smoke missile warheads and artillery rounds, at least. So if they were smoke generator pods like I was thinking I assume they'd have been mentioned. Ah well.

Comment: I have added an extra image with a medium tank having 8 of theses. Too many anti missile systems or too many anti personnel pods I think for this vehicle.

Comment: To me it kind of looks like something you might insert fuel cells into to power the vehicle. Seems like an odd place to put exhaust because of the fumes and heat might disrupt some instruments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would call those "[greebles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeble)" since they have no apparent gameplay effect in the description of either vehicle.  The first is a "Behemoth II Heavy Tank" (description at the [battletech.com forum](https://bg.battletech.com/forums/index.php?topic=41769.0) and at the [BattleTech wiki](https://www.sarna.net/wiki/Behemoth_II_Heavy_Tank)), the second is a "DI Schmitt" wheeled tank (description at the [battletech.com forum](https://bg.battletech.com/forums/index.php?topic=47176.0) and at the [BattleTech wiki](https://www.sarna.net/wiki/DI_Schmitt)).  Note that the anti-infantry effect of the turret-mounted machine guns is described for the latter, so if those were anti-personnel weapons they would also be described.

It is possible that the model designer intended them to be heat exhaust vents, since the description for the DI Schmitt notes that the installation of the 2 front flamers (just inboard of the 6 greebles) required an additional 6 heat sinks, which matches up nicely.

Comment: Exhaust vents sounds a good explanation to me, but the Demon Medium Tank has 8! (too many for a medium tank ¿?). I have updated the question with an extra image.

Comment: @KingMidas According to the [same sources](https://www.sarna.net/wiki/Demon_Medium_Tank), the Demon Medium Tank has 10 heat sinks, which seems appropriate to the power plant because even though it's only a medium tank the top speed is 110km/h and its primary armament is a pair of medium lasers.

Comment: Then makes more sense. The concept of "greebles" (that it is new to me) probably is correct. In any case, it is clear that it has not an easy answer.

Comment: I have the problem that, as there is no 100% security that are greebles, I do not know if marks this as an accepted answer or not.